# printing scanf input, potentially from between ignored non-letters

Tags: c, scanf

How do I get all of the array to print out? Right now, the array will print up to the last part, so if I input:

```
hel'lo hi
```

it will output

```
hel
lo
```

but not `hi`. 
Here is the code:

```
    char in[1000];
    printf("read these lines: ");
    while(scanf("%29[a-zA-Z]%*[^a-zA-Z]",in)==1){
        printf("%s\n",in);
    }
```

Comment: I didn't find a direct way, but I was thinking of reading the whole input then use [regex_search](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/regex_search/) to find the needed regex, but i think it needs at least `c++11`

Comment: @AmrAdel Too bad. I just removed the [tag:c++] tag as the title says "c" and the code looks like C.

Comment: IMHO, the question can be rephrased: "Why the `%*[^a-zA-Z]` does not consider a space?" I can imagine that spaces (like newlines) are handled in a special way in `scanf()` i.e. as delimiter. You could read the doc again with looking specifically concerning this issue. (I must admit that (in 20 years professional experience) I never used `scanf()` to that extend I learned here in SO the last year...)

Comment: I'm essentially trying to print out everything from standard input skipping punctuation, but the while loop doesn't seem to be printing everything.

Comment: Btw. I tried to dig a little bit deeper and tried out in [**ideone**](https://ideone.com/zsLf71). I even cannot reproduce. Hmm... May be, it's not a good idea to use such code in a productive solutions. IMHO, this resembles how things are done in e.g. JavaScript. In C, it's probably better to read a string and then parse it in any way. (And, to re-call Amr Adel's hint - there are even regex libs available which can be used in C.)

Comment: @Scheff what would the best way be to read the string and parse it by character? would you still use scanf?

Comment: If your intention was really to get and print everything then I would use `fgetc()` to get input character by character. Additionally, you cannot print every character which can be read. (There are non-printables in between.) If I write such code I usually do it this way: `c >= ' ' && c < 127 ? printf("%c", c) : printf("\\%02x", (unsigned char)c)`

Comment: If you don't want to read character by character you may also use `fread()` or `fgets()`. (Wasn't this already hinted?) This would read a buffer at once which then can be processed `char` by `char`.

Answer (score 0):

Parsing strings correctly with `scanf` can be quite tricky, which is why (from my personal experience) it is rarely used.

The reason, why your code apparently fails, may become clear, if instead of running your program interactively, we pipe the data into it.

```
$ printf "%s" "hel'lo hi" | ./scanf                                                                                                                                          
read these lines: hel
lo
hi
```

Putting the little annoyance with `hel` and `read these lines:` being on the same line aside, the program works as you intended.

The reason for this is, that `scanf` tries to consume as much characters as it can, until it encounters a character, which no longer matches the format string or the end of the input stream is reached.

Let's label the two directives `%29[a-zA-Z]` as **A** and `%*[^a-zA-Z]` and **B**.

If you pipe data, into your program, the following data will be on `stdin`

```
'h' 'e' 'l' '\'' 'l' 'o' ' ' 'h' 'i' <EOF>
----------- ---- ------- --- ------- -----
     A       B      A     B     A     EOF
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ~~~~~~~~~~~ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1st call       2nd call    3rd call
```

During the first loop, `scanf` consumes `'h' 'e' 'l' '\''`, because the following character `l` does not match the format string at this point. Then,  we have second run until `'h'` and finally a last run, which ends prematurely (without using **B**).

If you run your program interactively however, we have the following situation:

```
'h' 'e' 'l' '\'' 'l' 'o' ' ' 'h' 'i' '\n' <scanf blocks>
----------- ---- ------- --- ------- -----? // Maybe B can continue
     A       B      A     B     A     B   
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ~~~~~~~~~~~ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1st call       2nd call    3rd call
```

`scanf` returns only twice and then blocks, because there could be more data coming, which could match **B**.

We could try to switch the directives in format string, in order to consume the unwanted data first, `%*[^a-zA-Z]%29[a-zA-Z]`, this would allow us to also parse input like this `";hel;lo"`, but because the `%[` directive matches a *non-empty* sequence of characters, the original example `"hel'lo hi"` no longer works.

To properly solve this, with every corner case being handled, we have to resort to different approach and use two different `scanf` calls, one that consumes the unwanted data, and another that consumes the real data. I've also increased the precision in the calls to `1000`, because that's the size of your buffer. Why would you reserve 1000 bytes and use only 29?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main(void) {
    char in[1000];
    printf("read these lines: ");
    while (1) {
        if (scanf("%*[^a-zA-Z]") == EOF)
            break;
        if (scanf("%1000[a-zA-Z]", in) == EOF)
            break;
        printf("%1000s\n", in);
    }
}
```